# Join with Zend_Db, without having the columns of the joined tables

Tags: sql, join, zend-db-select

I use Zend_Db_Select to perform a query with a Join. I end up with the following SQL query :

```
SELECT `Utilisateur`.*, `Ressource`.*, `Acl_Cache`.*, `Role`.*, `UtilisateurRole`.* FROM `Utilisateur`
INNER JOIN `Ressource` ON Ressource.idJointure = Utilisateur.id
INNER JOIN `Acl_Cache` ON Acl_Cache.idRessource = Ressource.id
INNER JOIN `Role` ON Role.id = Acl_Cache.idRole
INNER JOIN `UtilisateurRole` ON UtilisateurRole.idRole = Role.id
WHERE (Ressource.tableJointure = 'Utilisateur') AND (UtilisateurRole.idUtilisateur = '2')
```

Why is Zend_Db adding this part is the SELECT clause :

```
, `Ressource`.*, `Acl_Cache`.*, `Role`.*, `UtilisateurRole`.*
```

I never asked this, and I don't want that. **How to prevent this behavior ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$db->select()
   ->from(array('alias1'=>'table_i_want_all_cols_on'))
   ->joinLeft(array('alias2'=>'table_i_want_no_cols_on'),
                'alias1.id = alias2.id',
                array()
   )
   ->joinLeft(array('alias3'=>'table_i_want_some_cols_on'),
                'alias3.id = alias1.id',
                array('col1', 'col2')
   );
```